# Larger amount of time is consumed while dumping Arabic data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My requirement is to dump Arabic data in PostGreSQL DB v8.4. But I have observed that while dumping Arabic data through java code,relatively larger amount of time is consumed as compared to dumping Eng data. Why is it so? I know latest version (for eg v9.4) is available but the migration of my project would still take 6 months.

Comment: Dumping how, exactly? Show your code.

Comment: @CraigRinger Its simple iteration on a ArrayList (Java) and insert queries

Comment: So by dumping you actually mean loading/inserting. Specifics please. Numbers. What is "relatively larger"? How big is the data set? Etc.